# Unity 4.6 GUI with rendertexture for upscaling - events in wrong location

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the new 4.6 Unity GUI system to create a bit of UI. I want to make this UI at a resolution of 400x300, then render to a texture which will then be drawn to the screen at a resolution of 800x600 (so double resolution). The problem is this: It doesn't work. The rendering is okay and I can correctly upscale the render texture and have it drawn to the screen, but the UI events aren't received in the correct position, and I can find no way to get around this.

So:

- Player resolution is 800x600 Render texture resolution is 400x300
- Main camera, called "UI Camera" renders to this texture (at 400x300)
- Canvas set to "Screen Space - Camera" pointing at "UI Camera". Under this is a button which is set to stretch to all sides (so fullscreen, 400x300)
- A second camera, called "Upscaling Camera".
- Another canvas set to "Screen Space - Camera" pointing at "Upscaling Camera".
- This canvas has it's GraphicRaycaster component removed. Under this is a RawImage displaying the render texture.

When I play, the UI is correctly rendered to the rendertexture, and then displayed on screen at 2x resolution, filling the screen. What is *not* working is the events - the button can only be interacted with when the mouse is in the lower-left quarter of the screen.

Conceptually, this makes sense. The button is occupying a space from (0, 0) to (400, 300) (starting at the bottom left of the screen), and now my player's resolution is 800x600, this rectangle only covers the bottom left corner. I get that.

So, with all that said, what can I do to fix this? I can't set the EventCamera on the GraphicRaycaster, so that's out. My next thought was to be somehow fudging the mouse positions. But honestly, I have no clue where to go.

(And in case somebody has a better way of doing this - I'm looking at a game working in 400x300 resolution which needs to be pixel-perfect. If I were to resize all my UI externally, that would mean that in-engine, they are essentially running on a half-pixel grid. Same goes for using the CanvasScaler component.)

Cheers for any help.